# Whats the reasoning behind odd integers rounding down when divided by 2?

Tags: ruby, math, integer

Wouldn't it be better to see an error when dividing an odd integer by 2 than an incorrect calculation?

Example in Ruby (I'm guessing its the same in other languages because ints and floats are common datatypes):

`39 / 2 => 19`

I get that the output isn't 19.5 because we're asking for the value of an integer divided by an integer, not a float (39.0) divided by an integer. My question is, if the limits of these datatypes inhibit it from calculating the correct value, why output the least correct value?

- Correct = 19.5
- Correct-ish = 20 (rounded up)
- Least correct = 19

Comment: Why is 20 more correct?

Comment: Rounding isn't simple - there's MANY different rules for rounding values, and there isn't one rule that will satisfy everyone. What if this program was actually calculating lengths of materials for processing? Better to be half an inch short rather than half an inch too long and jamming up a machine.

Comment: Good question. I guess 20 being more correct is more of a social construction than a mathematical reason since the distance to 19 and 20 from 19.5 is equal. For better or worse, its a common understanding to round up from .5.

Comment: There is a very good mathematical reason for it. It tells how many total `2`s are there in `39`.

Comment: @WojtekT Thank you. When expressed like that, 19 does indeed become more correct than 20.

Answer (score 6):

> Wouldn't it be better to see an error?

Throwing an error would be usually be extremely counter-productive, and computationally inefficient in most languages.

And consider that this is often useful behaviour:

```
total_minutes = 563;
hours   = total_minutes / 60;
minutes = total_minutes % 60;
```

---

> - Correct = 19.5
> - Correct-ish = 20 (rounded up)
> - Least correct = 19

Who said that 20 is more correct than 19?

Answer (score 3):

Among other reasons to keep the following very useful relationship between the sibling operators of division and modulo.

Quotient: `a / b = Q`

Remainder: `a % b = R`

Awesome relationship: `a = b*Q + R`.

Also so that integer division by two returns the same result as a right shift by one bit and lots of other nice relationships.

But the secret, main reason is that C did it this way, and you simply don't argue with C!

Comment: Of course, this all starts to fall apart for negative values... (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation#Remainder_calculation_for_the_modulo_operation)

Answer (score 1):

If you divide through 2.0, you get the correct result in Ruby.

```
39 / 2.0 => 19.5
```